# Simple XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following input file:

```
<!-- input.xml --> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
  <value>
    aaa
    <value>
      bbb
      <value>ccc</value>
    </value>
  </value>
</input>
```

Expected output:

```
<!-- output.xml --> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>bbb</li>
  <li>ccc</li>
</ul>
```

How should the XSLT file look like? I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/input">
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="//value">
        <li> <xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the the first result (aaa) also contains values from its subtree (bbb, ccc).

Comment: It's a good idea to say how the transformation should handle input documents that differ from your one example. For example, what should it do if there are two sibling value elements?

Comment: You are right but this is not a real-world use case, I am just trying to learn how XSLT works so this is just an example that I had trouble figuring out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to success in your case is that the template matching *value*
should replicate only text from the **current level**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
```

Actually, it is better to add *normalize-space()* to remove "additional"
white-space chars:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
```

After printing out of the content corresponding to the current level *li*
element, you should put *apply-templates* for child nodes only:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
```

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="input">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5w2

Answer (score 1):

Try `select="text()"` instead of `select="."` to only select the text content.